# How do I import Users/users collection?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor

So I have the following situation. I return an event with a bunch of participants in container A. Container B is a child of A and gets rendered as soon as the subscription is ready and the data is loaded. B should now use all the participant_ids to get the relevant user information (i.e. picture and name).

The way I usually access data in meteor is by doing **createContainer** like this:

```
const ComponentContainer = createContainer((props) => {
  const eventSub = Meteor.subscribe('getEvent',props.find.filter);
  const loading = !eventSub.ready();
  const eventData = loading ? null : Events.find(fin).fetch()[0];
  const eventDataExists = !loading && !!eventData;
  return {
    loading,
    eventData,
    eventDataExists,
  }
}, Component)
```

In the modul my component lives in I import **Events collection** like this:

```
import { Events } from '/imports/api/collections'
```

I have all my collections defined in /imports/api/collections like this:

```
import { Mongo } from 'meteor/mongo'
export const Events = new Mongo.Collection('events');
```

I also import my collections of the server like this (in /server/main.js)

```
import { 
  Events, 
  ...,
} from '/imports/api/collections';
```

Now as I would like to use a subscription to part of the users and where I have above Events.find(fin).fetch() I don't have that for users (because on the server side I get info via Meteor.users.find() ... if I try to declare Users collection in a similar fashion as with Events, I get a message regarding duplicate declaration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to declare a `Users` collection; the `accounts-base` package provides the collection and access to it with `Meteor.users`. [You can read more about that in the Meteor Guide on accounts-base](https://guide.meteor.com/accounts.html#accounts-base).

Keep in mind that only the user account of the currently-logged-in user is published, so that user cannot by default see information of other users. If you want to expose other users's data to the client you have to write your own custom publication.

Comment: Hi chazsolo, thx for your reply! Much appreciated. I do already have a user publication to expose only the public user data, I guess I was confused because I have to handle it differently. I.e. instead of doing Events.find({something}) I have to do Meteor.users.find({}). I guess my question was regarding how to import the users collection on the client side to use it (especially within the createContainer). Does this make sense?

Comment: @FabianBosler sure! I'm pretty sure you don't have to import `Meteor.users`, just `Meteor` and then you'll have access (http://docs.meteor.com/api/accounts.html#Meteor-users)

Comment: Yea, I have actually been doing that already. It just felt weird to have this somewhat different way to go about it than compared to every other collection. I mean it works and all, but it felt somewhat unituitive.

Comment: @FabianBosler agreed. I don't know the actual reasoning behind it, but, since it is an actual collection, I would presume they didn't want to conflict with any collections users could make and instead attach it to the Meteor object. Just a guess ;)